# How do I run a Ruby application on my local development machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wampserver

I have a Ruby web application that I would like to run/edit on my local development machine, I have followed various tutorials including this one:

http://www.alexbernard.fr/fichiers/blog/Installer-Ruby-On-Rails-sur-un-Wamp-Server.pdf

I'm stuck on step 5 I don't understand if Apache2 is a new directory or is the original wamp Apache directory. Step 6 I have added the code to the httpd.conf in my wamp apache config but the server will not restart - so I've gone wrong somewhere.

I'm really looking for some guidance to what i should download and what i need to run the application.

any help would be appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't follow that guide, use http://railsinstaller.org/

Comment: many thanks got it installed thanks , also followed http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WUdDdiu8kBs

Answer (score 1):

type rails s command from your project directory. You will get some errors, search for solutions. once your server is running with rails s command, you can access application with localhost:3000 in your browser address bar. good luck..

Comment: Thanks for you help got it insatlled now followed http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WUdDdiu8kBs